# Matplotlib dpi of different systems

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, size

I'm dealing with an issue of images size when produced by matplotlib with the function plt.savefig. Actually I'm using Google Colab to produce images which are:

Using:

> print(fig.get_size_inches(), fig.dpi, size)

I get:

> [6. 4.] 72.0 [432. 288.]

The same procedure done locally on Ubuntu produces a different image even if I'm using the same code. I have an array, which is the same on colab and on ubuntu, but after the saving with this library it becomes different. Any advice?

EDIT: In the end, using two different versions of matplotlib generates different outputs, even if everything else, as the inputs and other parameters, remain the same. Thanks David_sn for pointing it out.

Comment: check matplotlib versions on both environments (locally and Colab). Make sure to use the same version. Note that matplotlib 3.6.x might produce different results than previous version: I'm still digging into it.

Comment: matplotlib is 3.2.2 in both the environments. I agree with you on the 3.6.x, previously the outputs were considerably different using it in respect to the 3.2.2